# How can I write all named buffers?

Tags: command-line, save

I would like a command that saves every buffer that has a filename. `:h :wall` gives this:

```
                            *:wa* *:wall*
:wa[ll]     Write all changed buffers.  Buffers without a file
            name cause an error message.  Buffers which are
            readonly are not written.

:wa[ll]!    Write all changed buffers, even the ones that are
            readonly.  Buffers without a file name are not
            written and cause an error message.
```

So basically I want a command that would say "Write all changed buffers. Buffers without a filename are skipped/ignored." I don't care what happens to readonly buffers.

Is there an existing command that does this, or would I need to write a function to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like an ideal place to make use of the command [`:silent!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#:sil).

`:silent` can be inserted before other commands and its effect is to prevent display of "normal" (i.e. non-error) messages. Error messages still get displayed and may cause execution to halt.

`:silent!`, with added `!`, goes a step further and also suppresses messages caused by errors and prevents those errors from aborting execution.

So you should be able to use the latter along with `:wa!` thusly...

```
:silent! wa!
```

...to get your desired result:

1. Write changed buffers
2. Ignore buffers without a filename (error suppressed)
3. Write readonly buffers (which you don't have a preference for either way)